# Highlight menu item for the current page user is on

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to highlight this menu item so the user can see the page they are currently on. It can be bold or underlined, whatever really. If it can be done only using CSS that would be ideal.

here's what my inspect element looks like for the page :

[image]

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's just an example:

```
li.current-menu-item {
    // Your style Below */
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

or

```
li.current-menu-item a {
    /* Your style Below */
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dd614a;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, this didn't seem to make any change

Comment: Try to add !important a the end of the rule /e.g. underline !important).

Comment: Uhm... in the inspector the property is inherited?

Comment: Hm, not sure what you mean exactly. The theme seems to have generated the classes and I'm not sure what it would be inherited from, I added the span to the "Latest" menu item in attempt to isolate it.

Comment: In the inspector console you can check if the property is correctly set to the item you are interested in.

Comment: This is where I get confused. I'm not sure what property needs to be selected. I just know it's that menu I want to make the changes to.